# Notice: Undefined Index. How do I define the index?

Tags: php, undefined

I received a response of:

> Notice: Undefined index yy in Page1.php on line 11
>
> Notice: Undefined index mm in Page1.php on line 12
>
> Notice: Undefined index dd in Page1.php on line 13

What do I do to define these *yy, mm, dd*?

```
<?php
     $redirect_page = 'Page2.php';

     $_SESSION['yy'] = $_POST['yy'];   // This is on line 11
     $_SESSION['mm'] = $_POST['mm'];   // This is on line 12
     $_SESSION['dd'] = $_POST['dada']; // This is on line 13

    if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
        header('Location: ' . $redirect_page);
    }
?>

<HTML>
    <Form name="Page1" action="" method="POST">

        <select name="yy">
            <option value="2001">2001</option>
               // ...Another 100 years
        </select>

        <select name="mm">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
              // ... another 10 months
        </select>

        <select name="dd">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
               // ...another 29 days
        </select>

        <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
    </Form>
</HTML>
```

Comment: POST and GET data is only sent if there is a selection made. The easiest way to get around this is to have a default selection made in the form. Secondly, check the data before doing something with it using a function like `!empty()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try wrapping those post variables in the [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function:

```
$_SESSION['yy'] = isset($_POST['yy']) ? $_POST['yy'] : "";     // This is on line 11
$_SESSION['mm'] = isset($_POST['mm']) ? $_POST['mm'] : "";     // This is on line 12
$_SESSION['dd'] = isset($_POST['dada']) ? $_POST['dada'] : ""; // This is on line 13
```

Answer (score 6):

I know peole already aswered but I will give you a little tip. Use this little function below :

```
function _post($Var, $Default=''){
    return (isset($_POST[$Var]) === TRUE ? $_POST[$Var] : $Default);
}
```

You can set the default value in case the variable is not found. It will also take care of the undefined index error ;)

Undefined index mean that the entry was not found in the array. In this case, entries `yy`, `mm` and `dd` doesn't exist in the `$_POST` array. You have to check if they exists using the PHP language construct command **[isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)**. Use as follow :

```
$_SESSION['yy'] = _post('yy', date('Y')); // will be the value of $_POST['yy'] or it not found will be the current year
$_SESSION['mm'] = _post('mm', date('M')); // ... or will be the current month (MM)
$_SESSION['dd'] = _post('dd', date('d')); // ... or will be the current day (DD)
```

You can create different function based on your needs :

```
function _get($Var, $Default=''){
    return (isset($_GET[$Var]) === TRUE ? $_GET[$Var] : $Default);
}

function _session($Var, $Default=''){
    return (isset($_SESSION[$Var]) === TRUE ? $_SESSION[$Var] : $Default);
}

function _put($Var, $Default=''){
    return (isset($_PUT[$Var]) === TRUE ? $_PUT[$Var] : $Default);
}

function _delete($Var, $Default=''){
    return (isset($_DELETE[$Var]) === TRUE ? $_DELETE[$Var] : $Default);
}

function _files($Var, $Default=NULL){
    return (isset($_FILES[$Var]) === TRUE ? $_FILES[$Var] : $Default);
}
```

Comment: For your first function, you don't need the `TRUE` or the brackets. Just do `return isset($_POST[$Var]) ? $_POST[$Var] : $Default;`.

Comment: @halfer Yes, but it's more clear to read and it's also a standard way to write PHP code.

Comment: I disagree on both counts, though I know one or two people who also take the same view as you. For the sake of interest, my approach is to read `isset($x) ?` as "if $x is set" aloud, which I think makes more sense in English than "if $x is set equals true". But, it's a minor point; you get my +1 for a working solution.

Comment: @halfer Thank you. The other reason, even if it doesn't apply here, is the comparaison against a boolean. Let say you have a function that can return either `0`, `1`, `FALSE` or `TRUE` (bad design at start, but), you may want to use `===` to check against a boolean. If you use `if(myFunction())` then `1` and `TRUE` will be true in this case. However, using `if(myFunction() === TRUE)` will be true only if the function return `TRUE`. The concept apply here also even if isset return `FALSE` or `TRUE`.  From my PoV, everything must be standard and uniform across all the code. If someone else come

Comment: If someone else come to read my code, he will know that I am looking for `TRUE` and not `1` or `TRUE`. This apply to every language that is non-strict on 1 or TRUE statement, such as PHP and Javascript. However, in C#, what you are saying would be better because 1 is not TRUE. But, there's a compiler that will convert and fix everything at this point. Now the only reason left is to be able to read in a easier way for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You have to start the PHP session before to set the values​​:

```
<?php 
   session_start(); 

   $redirect_page= 'Page2.php';

   $_SESSION['yy'] = $_POST['yy'];
   $_SESSION['mm'] = $_POST['mm'];
   $_SESSION['dd'] = $_POST['dada'];

   // rest of code
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
if(isset($_POST['yy']))
    $_SESSION['yy'] = $_POST['yy'];
if(isset($_POST['mm']))
    $_SESSION['mm'] = $_POST['mm'];
if(isset($_POST['dd']))
    $_SESSION['dd'] = $_POST['dd']; // assuming it is $_POST['dd'] and not $_POST['dada']
```